# Jquery attr not working for required but will for title

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with attr while using the following:

```js
$("input[name='choice']").change(function() {
  if ($("#opt_2").is(":checked")) {
    $("#email").attr("required", true);
    $("#reasonreport").attr("required", true);
  } else {
    $("#email").removeAttr("required");
    $("#reasonreport").removeAttr("required");
  }
  if ($("#ch7").is(":checked")) {
    $("#reasonreport").attr("required", true);
  } else {
    $("#reasonreport").removeAttr("required");
  }
});
```

`#email` is an email input field and `#resonreport` is a textarea input.

When `#opt_2` is checked from a radio box it changed the email field to required but won't change the `#reasonreport` textarea to required. The following works fine:

```js
$('#reasonreport').attr('title', 'something');
```

Will add a title, but it's just the required attr that won't set, I've been scratching my head for a while now and can't for the life of me work out why.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What kinds of elements are they? (The HTML would help a lot. A [mcve] would help even more.)

Comment: The #email is an email input and the #reportingreason is a textarea input. Sorry left them out will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally what you're doing should be working, because boolean attributes are "true" when they're present at all (regardless of value) and "false" when they're absent. But then, jQuery's `attr` (still) blurs the lines between attributes and properties and is not the right choice when trying to handle properties: Use `prop` with `true` to enable and `false` to disable the property. This also lets you markedly simplify the code:

```
$("input[name='choice']").change(function() {
    $('#email, #reasonreport').prop('required', $('#opt_2').is(':checked'));
    $('#reasonreport').prop('required', $('#ch7').is(':checked'));
});
```

...but note that you also have a logic error: You're setting the `required` property of `#reasonreport` based on `opt_2`'s `checked` status, but then **overwriting** that based on `ch7`'s `checked` status. You may as well completely remove the code setting `#reasonreport`'s `required` in the `opt_2` stuff; it ends up doing nothing.

If your goal is to require `#reasonreport` if **both** `opt_2` and `ch7` are checked, you'll need to modify the code.

```
$("input[name='choice']").change(function() {
    var opt_2_checked = $('#opt_2').is(':checked');
    var ch7_checked = $('#ch7').is(':checked');
    $('#email').prop('required', opt_2_checked);
    $('#reasonreport').prop('required', opt_2_checked && ch7_checked);
});
```

Or use `||` instead of `&&` if the goal is to require it if **either** of them is checked.

Comment: Ive tried using .prop but still the same thing, email input is working fine and adding the required attr but the textarea is still not working

Comment: @Adam: I noticed just after clicking Post that you had a logic error, which I've updated to address.

Comment: superstar thanks for that I didnt even see the overwriting. Thank you!